# How can I update a pom.xml property in terminal in spring project?

Tags: java, spring, maven, terminal, pom.xml

Say, there is a property `customProp` in the pom.xml in my spring project.
2.4.snap

When I run my project, I can update its value like below

```
mvn clean install -DcustomProp=newValue
```

It's working well. It updates the value of `customProp` with `newValue`.
But I want to concat `newValue` with the previous value of `customProp`. So that the value of `customProp` will be `2.4.snapnewValue`.
How can I do that? 
Further, is it possible to replace `snap` with `newValue` so that the value of `customProp` will be `2.4.newValue`.

Comment: `-DcustomProp1=value -DcustomProp2=newValue` and in the pom.xml `<value>${customProp1}${customProp2}</value>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<properties>
  <customProp>snap</customProp>
</properties>

<version>2.4.${customProp}</version>
```

Would this be possible in your situation? Of course, use the correct tag where I'm using `<version>`.

---

The best way to approach this might be more like:

```
<properties>
  <customPropPrefix>2.4.</customPropPrefix>
  <customProp>snap</customProp>
</properties>

<version>${customPropPrefix}${customProp}</version>
```

Now you can specify both `-DcustomPropPrefix=2.4.` and `-DcustomProp=newValue`.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than build and clean your maven project forcefully it will sure update your maven project[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jsz2X.jpg)

Comment: Try not to put any external link here; and for this kind of answer you can easily explain the steps here since it's not very complicated to describe. If you do need an image for your explanation, it's recommended to put the image inside the answer instead of using the external link.